# How to get an unique id for a device (iPhone/iPad/AppleTV, etc) programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

How to get an unique id of a device like iPhone/iPad/AppleTV, etc programmatically?

I have tried below code in objective-c and swift both as mentioned below: -

Objective-c: `[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]`

Swift 3: `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString`

It gives me an identifier UUID. But I got some cases when it gives different identifier UUID as explained below: -

Suppose you installed app in device then it gives a UUID like **30C0DA8A-B35F-45B1-98DA-6D766CB42F1D**, if you re-installed without deleting app from device it gives the same UUID. I tried multiple times.
Now again install the same app after deleting the app from device then it gives different identifier UUID like **87CDC5C0-E744-4D60-9002-FA15BBBB6EDA**.

So this is not fulfilling the uniqueness identifier UUID requirement for a particular device.

**Question:** I need a UNIQUE Identifier for a particular device like Serial Number, IMEI, etc. Which always be unique whenever user installed app anytime.

I have also followed https://gist.github.com/0xced/566994, but someone said that this will not be accepted by Apple Store. **Is it true?**

I can't store any data in NSUserDefault/CoreData etc because these also deleted when user deletes app from device.

**How can I get an unique identifier for single device which should persist after app uninstall/reinstall?**

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get UUID, its related to application unique identifier. Try to get UDID.

Comment: This has been deprecated in iOS 5.

Comment: did you checked your device UDID?

Comment: I am working on iOS 9 and above. And there is no way to get UDID. If you know, please tell me.